# Asynchronous Modules

Tags: node.js, oop, asynchronous

Using the method found [here](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch6.html) when creating objects and immediately trying to access them, the class method are not accessibly, even though the object has been created. How can I juggle OOP in Node.js and being asynchronous? (I'm not so concerned about being blocking... This is *not* a script that is accessible to other (almost like a cronjob))

Modifying their code:

```
// Constructor
function Foo(bar, callback) {
  // always initialize all instance properties
  this.bar = bar;
  this.baz = 'baz'; // default value
  callback();
}
// class methods
Foo.prototype.fooBar = function() {
  return this.bar;
};
// export the class
module.exports = Foo;
```

If I were to async to try and juggle this

```
var p1;
var p2;
async.series([
    function(callback){
        new Foo("Foobar1", function(){
            p1 = this;
            callback(null, 'one');
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        new Foo("Foobar2", function(){
            p2 = this;
            callback(null, 'two');
        });
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
    console.log(p1); // this produces *something*, therefore its set
    console.log(p1.fooBar()); // nope!
});
```

I get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'fooBar'`

What am I doing wrong? How can I deal with being asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with being asynchronous. This is about `this` not being what you think it is.

Inside the callback, `this` is not bound to anything, so depending on `use strict`, it's either the global node object, or `null`.

In your constructor, try `callback.call(this)`.